# Second Order Linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a second order linear equation with constant coefficients, $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + c\frac{dy}{dx} + dy = g(x)$$
with general solutions $$ y_g(x)=e^{-4x} (C_1\cos(3x) + C_2\sin(3x)) + 7\sin(4x)$$

**Attempted solution**

Notice that $y_h(x) =  e^{-4x} (C_1\cos(3x) + C_2\sin(3x))$ and $y_p (x) = 7\sin(4x)$ with $y_g(x) = y_p(x) +y_h(x)$.

1) Find $c$ and $d$.

**Attempt**

The characteristic polynomial has roots
$$
-4+3i, -4-3i,
$$
hence it is
$$
p(\lambda)=\lambda^2+8\lambda+25.
$$
Hence the homogeoneous part is
$$
y''+8y'+25y=0
$$

2) Find the forcing function, $g(x)$.

I'm a bit confused here. I believe that $e^{-4x} (C_1\cos(3x) + C_2\sin(3x))$ is the forcingg function for $x^4 e^{-4x} (C_1\cos(3x) + C_2\sin(3x))$, but we're missing the $x^4$.

3)If the system is a mass-spring system with a mass of 10kg with displacement in meters, and time in seconds, what is the spring and damping constant?

4) What is the steady state solution?

Any help appreciated. i.e. next step to be taken..

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The characteristic polynomial has roots
$$
-4+3i, -4-3i,
$$
hence it is
$$
p(\lambda)=\lambda^2+8\lambda+25.
$$
Hence the homogeoneous part is
$$
y''+8y'+25y=0
$$
Next look for a paticular solution of the form
$$
y_p=a\cos 4x+b\sin 4x.
$$

Comment: @Yigoros S. Smyrlis How do you derive the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: $e^{-4x}\cos 3x$ and $e^{-4x}\sin 3x$ correspond to the roots $\lambda_{1,2}=-4\pi 3i$. Now $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=-8$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2=25$. $c=-$sum of the room while $d=$product of the roots.

Comment: Could you give a hint regarding the next step?

Comment: S. Symrlis why are we looking for a particular solution of that form?